# Adds a state store to the underlying Topology before StreamsBuilder started

Tags: spring-kafka

Is there a way in StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer to add state store to the underlying Topology before StreamsBuilder started, in order to use it in the processor or transformer.

when using the Kafka Streams DSL there is such a way

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.addStateStore(getStoreBuilder());
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an [open pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1305) to add a topology customizer to the factory bean but it hasn't had any attention for a while. The author doesn't appear to have responded to the last review comments.

Maybe it can be enhanced to allow customizing the builder itself.

I can take a look at it next week and try to get it into next Wednesday's releases.

Comment: I look to the PR, I am with your proposal to enhance it by customizing the builder instead of keeping create customizer for each specific case.